Why is WPGraphQL Smart Cache not working?
I installed the WPGraphQL Smart Cache plugin on my Wordpress site and there is no caching when sending a request to the server.
There is no X-Cache header in the Response headers.
Server configuration:
– ubuntu 20
– nginx 1.18
– php 8.2
I tried using local and object cache — not working.

What stack/hosting provider are you using? My understanding is Smart Cache only includes built in support for a few hosting providers.
See https://github.com/wp-graphql/wp-graphql-smart-cache/blob/main/docs/network-cache.md#hosting-guide

For a complete answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79071935/11259041
TL;DR The Smart Cache plugin is one side of the caching coin. To use it you must have a compatible cache that can leverage it. The X-Cache header is added by a compatible Network Cache. The Object Cache is most likely working but does not modify headers, it only modifies the GraphQL response to note object caching is working.
